# Ideal with no zero divisors implies integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I'm trying to figure out a solution to the question:

> If a commutative ring $R$ has a nontrivial proper ideal $I$ that contains no nontrivial zero divisor of $R$, is $R$ an integral domain?

I haven't been able to find a counterexample, and it is simple to answer this in the affirmative if $I$ is prime. However, I have found it very difficult to make progress in the general case. I considered the contrapositive, and obviously in a ring that is not an integral domain there is *an* ideal that contains zero divisors, but I can't figure out how to show that *every* ideal contains zero divisors.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a proof? Or a counterexample? Thanks so much, and I apologize that I don't have more progress to show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring containing a zero divisor $r \ne 0$, and let $I$ be any non-trivial ideal of $R$.

Since $I$ is an ideal, $rI \subset I$, but every multiple of $r$ is also a zero divisor. Either $rI \ne 0$, and therefore $I \supset rI$ contains a non-zero zero divisor, or $rI = 0$, which also implies that all elements of $I$ are zero divisors (at least one of which is non-zero, since $I$ is non-trivial).

Thus, every non-trivial ideal of $R$ contains a zero divisor.

Comment: So you mean that if there exists a non-trivial ideal $I$ of $R$ which contains no zero divisor then $R$ itself contains no zero divisor. Am I right @M.Vinay? But then it proves the result exactly what OP needs.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Yes, exactly. It seems too easy, so I'm still not entirely confident about what I've myself written here (despite not being able to see any flaws in the reasoning).

Comment: @M.Vinay: Don't worry. It's correct.

Comment: Thanks! Super clean proof.